# Did Johnson and Johnson really pay a 25% quarterly dividend in 1978?

Tags: stock-markets, historical-data

I looked through some of the old Dow Jones stocks for a project I'm working on and found some inconsistency with JNJ stock. For a share price of $1.66 they appeared to pay $0.42 in quarterly dividends which would more than double any money put into the stock within a year. [See Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/JNJ/history?period1=189298800&period2=315529200&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo)

By simply investing $10k into the stock every year, the investor would have $5 billion in 45 years. Is this correct or is this a mistake? If so what happened to a Dow Jones listed company that they could afford dividends like this? Or am I just reading it wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, your billionaire premise is not correct.

Most people don't realize that share price drops by the exact amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date when the stock exchanges adjust the closing price.

If you have a $100 stock that is going ex-dividend tomorrow morning for $1, in the morning the adjusted close will be $99.  IOW, you will incur a capital loss in the amount of $1 while becoming entitled to receive your $1 dividend on the Pay Date.  For that reason, you would not be doubling your JNJ money in one year after receiving four dividends.  In fact, an ex-dividend results in zero increase or decrease in the value of your position.

When a stock splits, the number of shares increases and the price decreases, per the nature of a split.  If you own 100 shares of a $100 stock and it splits two for one, on the day of the split you will own 200 shares at $50.  In both cases, your position value is $10k.

My guess is that Yahoo Finance is reporting split adjusted stock prices (many of them over the years) but it did not adjust the dividend as well, making it appear that JNJ paid a 100% dividend back then.  Yahoo is not a rock star when it comes to reliability :->)

Comment: Yes, but it is unfortnately the only place on the entire internet where I can get legacy finance data. Thanks though, I think I'll just kick JNJ off my stock carousel. I hope the other datapoints are more or less correct

Comment: If the JNJ data is bad because Yahoo is not adjusting the dividend then any other data from Yahoo that paid a dividend is likely to be bad.  You can verify my guess about this being the cause by looking up the dates of stock splits and looking up the historical dividends for a stock.  With that info, you'll be able to determine if Yahoo is making the error that I suggested.  How much data are you looking for?  How many years?  Daily, weekly, monthly?  How many stocks?

Comment: Its just for a data visualization project, mainly about how to use d3. I think I'll even work this error into the presentation to show how unverified data is unlikely to be trusted. But for a bit of stock data to fill a fancy graph it should still fit the bill

Comment: JNJ had four dividends in 1978, each of $0.425.  There were no other corporate actions in 1978 (such as stock splits, stock dividends etc.).  At the time it was trading in the $70-$90 range, which is nothing like 25%.  Source: US Stock database at Norgate Data.

Comment: @user2741831 - Yahoo  got the dividend right.  It was .472 per quarter in 1978 and .499 in 1979.  I have access to daily data back to 1980.  I compared it to Yahoo's O/H/L/C and it matched.  So they got the daily prices right as well.  They just didn't explain that daily price was split (and dividend) adjusted but that the dividends were not split adjusted.  Since 1978, they had 5 stock splits.  The first was 3:1 and the next four were 2:1. If you want to adjust, divide the 1978 annual dividend by 48 and divide that by share price, say $1.65) and you get a 2.12% dividend which makes sense.

Comment: "In fact, an ex-dividend results in zero increase or decrease in the value of your position."  That's only true if you were to sell the stock immediately.  The stock price is set by what people are willing to pay for it, not by the exchange.  Bookkeeping and investing are not the same thing.

Comment: Look here at [UVV](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UVV/history?p=UVV) price history.  The last dividend was issued on Oct.4.  On the third the close was 54.96 and the adjusted was 54.20 (i.e. less the $0.76 dividend.)  Around three weeks later the price closed at 55.35.  Please explain how that comes out to a zero increase or decrease in a position.

Comment: @JimmyJames Even if the exchange didn't automatically adjust, the market makers would do it as a practial matter. Unless some news about the company comes out at the same time, the dividend has the most impact on the company's value.

Comment: @Barmar I understand all of that, but the effect is temporary.  To say that dividends don't have any impact on your investment value is nonsense.  In very simple terms the return of your investment is the increase in value plus your dividends.  You never need to consider the ex-dividend price because that's not a real transaction price.  If you think that the ex-dividend price is a 'real' price, you must believe that the exchange sets the price of stocks.

Comment: @JimmyJames Prices are relative. Suppose the market decides that the company is worth 1% more today than it was yesterday. If a dividend is declared, the price will go up 1% from the ex-dividend price, not its pre-dividend price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102840/discussion-between-falco-and-jimmyjames).

Answer (score 27):

JNJ did pay $0.42 per share in quarterly dividends, but the unadjusted (for splits) share price in the late 70s was $67-$80. It appears as though you're looking at share prices which are adjusted for splits and dividend per share prices which aren't adjusted for splits.